# How to search for item in list and start processing until the end of list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to process a list but what I wanted is to initialized the starting item of the list. For instance, sometimes, I need to start only from `AXD2` until the last item of mylist `34SDF`. How can it be done?

```
mylist = ['ABCD121','2132ASX','S2ADSD','AXD2','HDDW12','574S3','PIF4W''4FSD5','34SDF']
for item in mylist:
    print (item)
    print ("doing something with the item")
```

Comment: from `AXD2` inclusive?

Comment: I just wanted to start from AXD2 until the last item of the list

Comment: again, "start from AXD2" including `AXD2` or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this by getting the index of your predefined start item and iterate through the list starting from it's position as so:

```py
# Define list
mylist = ['ABCD121','2132ASX','S2ADSD','AXD2','HDDW12','574S3','PIF4W''4FSD5','34SDF']

# Define start item
startItem = 'AXD2'

# Get start items index
startItemIndex = mylist.index(startItem)

# Iterate through list beginning with index of start item
for item in mylist[startItemIndex:]:
    print (item)
    print ("doing something with the item")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it

```
mylist = ['ABCD121', '2132ASX', 'S2ADSD', 'AXD2', 'HDDW12', '574S3', 'PIF4W', '4FSD5', '34SDF']

start_processing = False  

for item in mylist:
    if start_processing:
        print(item)
        print("Doing something with the item")


    if item == 'AXD2':
        start_processing = True
```